# In Excel 2007, how do I remove duplicate lines, while merging data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, merge, duplicate

To help you understand the question, here is a sample:

I have this:

Name  -  Account# -   Address - . . .- phone
Mr. A . .  4278  . . . .   123 Main .  . . 555-1212
Mr. B  . . 7532   . . . .  435 Ocean
Mr. B  . . 7532 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .               555-3456
Mr. C  . . 8394 . . . .    789 Harbor. . 555-8765

I want this:

Name - Account# -  Address -  phone
Mr. A  . . 4278   . . . .   123 Main  .  555-1212
Mr. B  . . 7532  . . . .   435 Ocean  555-3456
Mr. C  . . 8394 . . . .    789 Harbor 555-8765

There will be more columns, some with data, others without.
So, I want to remove duplicates, while merging unique data.

Ideally, if possible, there may be unique data, such as dates, where I would keep the later date.

Thank you.

Comment: This is difficult to do in excel, you have to know what are the unique identifiers and logical operations to merge the columns, what happens when 2 rows have value in the columns? Without a sample data file it would be hard to recommend a way. A simple method would be to fill blank cells, with values from above it, assuming the rows are sorted.

Comment: Thank you.  I used your suggestion to handle my problem.  It took a bunch of steps, but a lot less than doing everything manually.  I do not see how to mark this as answered.  If you do, be my guest.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted a simple way would be:

1. `select all blank cells` and enter formula to show data from cell
   above `=r[-1]` with R1C1 format, or some other method.
2. Then assuming you know the unique keys, delete all duplicate rows.
3. You could highlight duplicate rows by conditional formatting `=countif(A:A,A1)>0` or similar method.

Hope that helps.

Additional resources:

- [Conditional Formatting](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/compare-two-lists.html)